# How to use Ropsten after ETH upgrade

Tags: remix, metamask, ropsten

Since the PoS update (?) of Ethereum, Ropsten has disappeared from the available test networks in Metamask. Is there a way to reconnect to Ropsten with Metamask to keep using Remix to write and test Smart Contracts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that testnet was deprecated. To test contracts consider using Goerli and [Sepolia](https://sepolia.dev/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The Rinkeby and Ropsten testnets have been deprecated as of October 5th, 2022. You can use Goerli or Sepolia network instead.

See: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059213492-ETH-on-Sepolia-and-Goerli-networks-testnets-